# How to change the PDF producer metadata with XeLaTeX on MikTeX

Tags: xetex, hyperref, pdf, metadata

I tried to change the PDF Producer of the generated PDF file with XeLaTeX, but it always be "MikTeX-xdvipdfmx (0.7.8)", if the PDF is generated with `pdflatex`, it will change as I wish, does anybody know how to change it with `xelatex`? I'm using MikTeX2.9.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfproducer={xelatex}]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't. hyperref already tries to change it but xetex overwrites this changes.

Comment: @Ulrike: it doesn't make any difference, but it's xdvipdfmx. It happens also on Mac OS X, even with xdv2pdf (the producer is Mac OS X 10.6.6 Quartz PDFContext). The `xdv` file contains the requested "Producer" field.

Comment: @egreg: Please turn Ulrike's and your comments into an answer.

Comment: I opened a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/93/) at the `XeTeX` project.

Comment: it seems that this has been/will be fixed in the next update, see https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/76#issuecomment-442066394

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `xdvipdfmx` program that post processes the `xdv` file produced by XeTeX into a PDF defines a "Producer" string on its own, overwriting the one defined in the document.

There's apparently no way to change this behavior, which happens also with the (obsolete) postprocessor xdv2pdf available on Mac OS X.

If one compiles with XeTeX without calling `xdvipdfmx`, the requested "Producer" string is found in the `xdv` file. Indeed the call

```
xelatex -no-pdf test.tex && strings test.xdv | grep Producer
```

(where `test.tex` is the example file in the question) prints

```
pdf:docinfo<</Title()/Subject()/Creator(LaTeX with hyperref package)/Author()/Producer(\376\377\000x\000e\000l\000a\000t\000e\000x)/Keywords()>>
```

Answer (score 3):

As [pointed out correctly by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21477/3323), `xdvipdfmx` overrides any producer you try to set in the PDF metadata with its own `xdvipdfmx (<version number>)`. However, you can include so-called [XMP metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) information in addition to the normal metadata catalog in a PDF document. This offers you the possibility of setting the `<pdf:Producer>`, which is displayed in Adobe Reader instead of the normal `/Producer` field if present.

Currently, XMP data can be added to a LaTeX document using one of the packages [`xmpincl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xmpincl) or [`hyperxmp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp). While the former is more flexible, it requires you to [create an `.xmp` file yourself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41492/3323). Furthermore, as it only works with pdfTeX, it won't work for your configuration.

So in your case, I would recommend using the `hyperxmp` package: It takes care of generating the necessary stucture automatically, and it works with a number of TeX engines. As it uses the `pdfauthor`, `pdfproducer`, ... fields set with `hyperref`, simply loading it with `\usepackage{hyperxmp}` is enough to generate the XMP metadata:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\hypersetup{pdfproducer={xelatex}}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: Adobe Reader's "Document Properties" dialogue]

If you're using XeLaTeX in combination with the [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class, the question [Is there a poisonous interaction between memoir, hyperref, and hyperxmp?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46068/3323) might be of interest to you.

However, keep in mind that this only works for XMP-aware programs, other programs will still display `xdvipdfmx (<version number>)`. Furthermore, `xdvipdfmx` compresses all PDF objects including the XMP metadata, which is fine for Adobe, but may confuse other programs (see [the `hyperxmp` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperxmp/hyperxmp.pdf#page=7) for more information).

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to delete the annoying "xdvipdfmx (0.x.x)" and here is a solution for windows users (only TeX Live!):

**Be careful you have to patch the executable, do it on your own risk and make an backup of the file first.**

1. Get a Hex-Editor (I'm using the freeware CFF Explorer). Assuming your using it too, open the file [xdvipdfmx.exe](http://ftp.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/bin/win32/xdvipdfmx.exe?revision=30827&view=co), go to "Hex Editor" and click on search symbol.
2. Than paste `786476697064666D78000000257320282573290050726F6475636572`in Hex searchbox and click on find (this is equivalent to `xdvipdfmx...%s (%s).Producer` on the ASCII side).
3. If you want do delete the pdfproducer String fill with zeros like in the following image, i.e. do not remove the Hex string `50726F6475636572` (or in ASCII `Producer`):

   [image: patching the executable]
4. Save the file in the proper directory (using `texlive2013` it would be `.../texlive/2013/bin/win32`). Now you can compile your document using XeTeX.
5. On every update of this executable you will be forced to to this again.

*Note:* of course you've to use hyperref package for the other metasettings like pdfcreator.

Comment: A good Hex editor is the ([Freeware Hex Editor XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm)). It has a builtin script interpreter, so the replacement task could be automated, what makes life easier when you have to repeat this some time in future.

Comment: If you want to automate the process I wouldn't recommend using a Hex-Editor but using a search and replace patcher like `dup2` or `uPPP` would be a good choice.