# How to add copyright information to PDF metadata

Tags: metadata, copyright, hyperxmp

## The Last(?) Word

I have now accepted @MatthewLeingang's answer. This directs me to the `hyperxmp` package, which appears to be the simplest solution (for me as a very-end user). The fact that this doesn't work in *my*  workflow and environment isn't Matthew's fault.

To chase the rest of my problem, which appears to involve a conflict with `memoir`, readers may be interested in [this spin-off question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46068/is-there-a-poisonous-interaction-between-memoir-hyperref-and-hyperxmp).

Thank you all again for your help.

---

## Progress Update 1:

First, flouting convention, my sincere thanks to all who have answered or commented (duly upvoted). Special thanks to @diabonas, whose sample PDF does indeed contain a copyright notice.

However, there may be a clue here: while his PDF says this:

> PDF Producer: XeTeX 0.9997

mine says this:

> PDF Producer: xdvipdfmx (0.7.8)

Now, I'm processing it with XeLaTeX *via* `latexmk`, but to keep myself honest, I re-did it with just XeLaTeX, with the same result.

---

## Progress Update 2:

Here's an MWE that fails, and gives "PDF Producer: xdvipdfmx (0.7.8)":

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={Brent Longborough},
    pdftitle={O Hai},
    pdfcopyright=Copyright © 2012 by Brent Longborough. All rights reserved.}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

By just changing the document class to article, we get "PDF Producer: XeTeX 0.9997", and the copyright notice appears!

---

## Original Question:

Using XeLaTeX. I want to add two pieces of metadata to a PDF: copyrighted status and the copyright notice.

I'm already using `hyperref` in the document, and I have no special worries about "overheads", only about keeping the workflow simple.

On the principle of "monkey see, monkey do", I tried this to no avail:

```
\hypersetup{%
    pdfinfo={%
        CopyrightStatus={Copyrighted},
        CopyrightNotice={Copyright © 2012 by Brent Longborough}
        }
    }
```

So far, I have been unable to find the correct tag names, or to discover even whether I have a chance.

All suggestions are welcome, but I'd especially like a pointer to the book of tag names for PDF metadata.

---

The answers and comments from Martin and EGreg deserve some additional explanation on my part.

My PDF reader is PDF Xchange Viewer from Tracker Software. When I view the Document Properties, and select the "Additional Metadata..." button, a [third] window appears in which there appear a dropdown labelled "Copyright Status:", with options "Unknown", "Copyrighted", and "Public Domain"; and a text box labelled "Copyright Notice:":

[image: screenshot of PDF Xchange Viewer's windows]

So you can see the source of my half-blind groping for metadata tags...

So, I guess what I'm *really* asking is "What tag names should I be using to fill in these fields?"

---

After hacking at the PDF (using @egreg's tip and then the viewer itself), I found the Copyright stuff in some RDF dc: namespace. I have since tried using [the hyperxmp package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp), but without success (nothing shows up in the PDF), and I suspect that may be because it only works for pdfLaTeX.

---

I have also tried @MatthewLeingang's answer, but can confirm that it definitely requires pdfLaTeX, and I really don't want to go back.

Comment: `xdvipdfmx` adds the info to the PDF dictionary; you can see it if you call `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -z 0" file`, which sets compression level to 0, and then look at the PDF file. How to use this information is perhaps beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: You'll have to ask Tracker Software for information on what to add to the PDF.

Comment: @doncherry: Thanks for the image; sorry I was too lazy.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: You're welcome. If Wikipedia's down already, we have to live up to our [wikiness](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) `:)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As egreg notes, rights information is not part of the document information directory.  But it can be included in the document's extensible metadata profile.

Here are two solutions that work with Adobe Acrobat and `pdflatex`.  I don't know if you will see the metadata in the same place as you do with Acrobat; PDF XChange Viewer is a Windows app and I have a Mac so I can't test it.

Also (*potential showstopper, wish I had noticed this earlier*) neither solutions works with `xetex`.  Perhaps they could be cajoled but that would require patching the package.

## xmpincl

1. Make sure you have the [`xmpincl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xmpincl) package.  It's in TeX-live.
2. Create a basic XMP file like this:

```xml
    <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.2-c001 63.139439, 2010/09/27-13:37:26        ">
       <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
          <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
                xmlns:xmpRights="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/rights/">
             <xmpRights:Marked>True</xmpRights:Marked>
          </rdf:Description>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
                xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
             <dc:rights>
                <rdf:Alt>
                   <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">Copyright (C) 2012 by Brent Longborough.  All rights reserved.</rdf:li>
                </rdf:Alt>
             </dc:rights>
          </rdf:Description>
       </rdf:RDF>
    </x:xmpmeta>
```

Let's call it `copyright.xmp`.  If you want to grant more rights you can; you just need something more detailed.  Creative Commons has a page to help you [generate an XMP file](http://www.creativecommons.org/choose/).

3. Include this license file in your document like this:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \title{My article}
   \author{Brent Longborough}
   \usepackage{xmpincl}
   \includexmp{copyright}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \begin{document}
   \maketitle
   \lipsum
   \end{document}
   ```

That's it!  When I open the document in Adobe Acrobat I can see the copyright information in the expected place.  If I select File > Properties ... and click on "Additional Metadata..." it's there.

[image]

## hyperxmp

The [`hyperxmp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp) implements extra document information keys `pdfcopyright` and `pdfcopyrighturl` that can be declared in much the same way as `\pdfinfo` keys.  Under the hood it creates the XMP file for you.  So you only need a file like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{My article}
\author{Brent Longborough}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={Brent Longborough},
    pdfcopyright={Copyright (C) 2012 by Brent Longborough.  All rights reserved.}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Also doesn't work in `xetex`, though.

Comment: Matthew, I'm really grateful for the effort you've put into your answer, and I've +1ed it. However, unfortunately, as you point out, xmpincl doesn't support XeLaTeX. As I'm happier to give up the metadata before I give up XeTeX, no deal, I'm afraid; please don't think me ungrateful...

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: no problem.  After I realized it wouldn't work for you under your current workflow I decided to submit anyway in case others found it useful.

Comment: Absolutely right - one of my reasons for upvoting it.

Comment: `(x)dvipdfmx` uses a different method than `pdftex` to register information in the PDF; there is something about this in the TUGboat article retrievable by `texdoc dvipdfmx`, but it's quite scanty.

Comment: Since version 1.2, [`hyperxmp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp) should be compatible with XeTeX/xdvipdfmx, thus solving @Brent.Longborough's problem.

Comment: @diabonas: Sorry, doesn't solve it (1.4)

Comment: @Brent.Longborough That's weird... I tested the above MWE with an up-to-date TeX Live 2011 installation (Windows), and viewed the resulting file with PDF-XChange Viewer 2.5, which [displayed the copyright information](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MmUWw.png). This is the generated PDF file: [hyperxmp-copyright.pdf](http://www.pdf-archive.com/2012/02/27/hyperxmp-copyright/hyperxmp-copyright.pdf). Does this work for you?

Comment: @diabonas: Hmm, brilliant!. I can see a mysterious difference: in your PDF, PDF Producer shows as "XeTeX 0.9997", while in mine it shows as "xdvipdfmx (0.7.8)". Any ideas, anyone? (Don't you hate it when it does that?)

Comment: As far as I know `xdvipdfmx` always declares itself as producer, overriding whatever is in the source file.

Comment: @egreg: I can now narrow it down to switching from article to memoir and back.

Comment: @egreg That's true, `xdvipdfmx` overrides the `/Producer` field in the PDF metadata. However, you can specify a `<pdf:Producer>` field in the XMP metadata, which is displayed instead of the PDF metadata field if present (and not overwritten by `xdvipdfmx`).

Comment: @egreg Also see [How to change the PDF producer metadata with XeLaTeX on MikTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46128/3323).

Comment: I think, the second option with `hyperxmp` does work with `xelatex` at the moment.

Answer (score 11):

The main reference should be the "PDF Reference book", fourth edition, that on page 714 lists the known entry types for the *document information dictionary*:

> Title, Author, Subject, Keywords, Creator, Producer, CreationDate, ModDate, Trapped

On page 713 it says

> ***Note:*** *Although viewer applications can store custom metadata in the document information dictionary, it is inappropriate to store private content or structural information there; such information should be stored in the document catalog instead (see Section 3.6.1, “Document Catalog”).*

However, on page 882 (Appendix E), it says

> ***Note:*** *New keys for the document information dictionary (see Section 10.2.1, “Document Information Dictionary”) or a thread information dictionary (in the I entry of a thread dictionary; see Section 8.3.2, “Articles”) need not be registered.*

Not the expected answer, I guess. PDF viewers won't know how to access the information, if they are not programmed to.

### EDIT

With Adobe Reader X your keys are recognized:

[image]

Comment: Cool. The disadvantage of this approach is that a machine does not know what these keywords mean. XMP uses RDF, a data-description framework with namespaces.  So when one agent says something about a resource using, for instance, Dublin Core metadata, other agents can begin to understand it. But I am known to go off on massive metadata tangents...

Comment: I agree, but adding XMP support to `(x)dvipdfmx` seems not to be an easy task, considering the scantiness of the documentation.

Comment: maybe not.  `xmpincl.sty` is 100 lines long and boils down to these commands: `\pdfcompresslevel=0\immediate\pdfobj stream attr {/Type /Metadata /Subtype /XML}
      file{#1.xmpi}
\pdfcatalog{/Metadata \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R}`.  So it's only a few things to translate to `\special`s, IIUC.

Comment: There's some discussion of this, which seems to suggest how one would add PDF objects to XeTeX, at http://www.tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2011-August.txt (search for "analogues of \pdfobj?")

Answer (score 4):

Your code will work (as egreg points out) and write the keys and their values to the PDF info dict, but I don't know of any standardised keys for this information. You'll probably have better luck with [XMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) (sorry, Wikipedia is blacked out because of SOPA). There isn't much support for XMP with LaTeX, though.

Comment: There is a [latex package for including XMP metadata](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/tex-archive//macros/latex/contrib/xmpincl/).  Is XMPP the same as XMP?

Comment: No, `XMP` is correct, while `XMPP` is the protocol used by jabber/googletalk etc. The pagetitle is still visible on @Martin's wikipedia link. ;-)

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Yeah. It's mostly from 2005 and works somewhat.

Comment: There is another package http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp

Comment: @matth: Yes, I've now tried that, but it just seems to omit *all* my metadata (maybe it needs pdfLaTeX?). I've added a note to the question. Thank you.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough The manual of `hyperxmp` says that with XeTeX one needs to disable compression (with the `-z 0` trick I mentioned before).

Comment: @egreg: Yes, just to keep a clear conscience, I've just tried that again. Sorry, same (empty) result, though the other "normal" fields are there OK.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Perl available and the CPAN module `Image::ExifTool` installed, you can use

```
exiftool -@ copyright.txt pdffile.pdf`
```

where `copyright.txt` contains something like

```
-d
%Y
-copyright<Copyright ©$createdate, Brent Longborough
```

to create a dated copyright entry.

The advantages of this approach are that it can be easily automated and the copyright year is created automatically. Apart from the need to install the tool, the disadvantages are one more file to be maintained (but probably in a shared location) and one extra step when doing things manually.