# Is there a poisonous interaction between memoir, hyperref, and hyperxmp?

Tags: xetex, hyperref, memoir, incompatibility, copyright

In [another, now rather confused, question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41461/how-to-add-copyright-information-to-pdf-metadata), I'm struggling to get copyright information into a PDF produced by `memoir`.

The investigations so far have led to this problematical MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={Brent Longborough},
    pdftitle={O Hai},
    pdfcopyright={Copyright © 2012 by Brent Longborough. All rights reserved.},
    }
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

which produces a PDF with the copyright notice successfully included in the metadata, and with the "PDF Producer" set to "XeTeX 0.9997"

However, if I change the document class to:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
```

then I get no copyright notice, and the PDF Producer is now set to "xdvipdfmx (0.7.8)".

After an hour or so ploughing through `memoir.sty` and `memhfixc.sty`, I'm flummoxed. Does anyone have any idea where to look next?

Comment: Is there a missing left brace in the `pdfcopyright` line?

Comment: @Seamus: Well spotted, actually, I think it's missing both left *and* right (as the right one you can see actually closes `\hypersetup{`)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is actually a timing problem: The metadata has to be inserted before the final `\clearpage` command, otherwise, it isn't written to the PDF document any more. However, `memoir` issues a `\clearpage` with

```
\AtBeginDocument{\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\dol@stsheet\dol@stpage}}
```

so the code used by `hyperxmp`

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
   % [...]
      \AtEndDocument{%
        \hyxmp@find@metadata
        \hyxmp@embed@packet
      }%
   % [...]
}
```

is too late as `\hyxmp@find@metadata` and `\hyxmp@embed@packet` are executed after `\clearpage`.

To solve this, you can manually issue

```
\makeatletter
  \AtEndDocument{\hyxmp@find@metadata\hyxmp@embed@packet}
\makeatother
```

in your document's preamble.

#### Minimal test code:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\makeatletter
  \AtEndDocument{\hyxmp@find@metadata\hyxmp@embed@packet}
\makeatother
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={Brent Longborough},
    pdftitle={O Hai},
    pdfcopyright=Copyright © 2012 by Brent Longborough. All rights reserved.}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that fixes. +1, accepted, and my heartiest congratulations.

Comment: Worth filing a bug report perhaps? But whose bug is this? memoir or hyperxmp?

Comment: @Seamus: I'll talk to Lars. I think the right place for this is in `memhfixc.sty`, but I have no idea where.

Comment: Might also be an idea to talk to Heiko (but please do send me an email, I tend to forget what I have read online)

Comment: @daleif: Sent!! Thanks. (I do too, especially when it annoys me, as it often does these days.)

Comment: Just an update for the readers here. Heiko did a really nice analysis of the problem. It seems that `hyperxmp` make some assumptions that are not always present. Plus `(x)dvipdfm(x)` has no proper support for the Producer key.