# Copyright metadata into Adobe Reader using pdflatex

Tags: pdf, metadata, copyright, hyperxmp

Ok, first of all I'm quite aware there are a couple of question that address this issue.  More in specific:

1. [How to add copyright information to PDF metadata](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41461/how-to-add-copyright-information-to-pdf-metadata/41477#41477)
2. [Eliminate/Edit PDF properties added by pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23235/eliminate-edit-pdf-properties-added-by-pdflatex)
3. [Is there a poisonous interaction between memoir, hyperref, and hyperxmp?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46068/is-there-a-poisonous-interaction-between-memoir-hyperref-and-hyperxmp)

I tried using the [`hyperxmp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp) package, as described [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41492/27833) in question 1 , but I still didn't see the copyright property.  All I got was a `PTEX.Fullbanner` with value `This is MikTeX 2.9.4535(1.40.13)`.

Question 2 refers to many document properties, and although I have used them (more specifically, I'm using `\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}`), I wasn't able to use the `pdfcopyright` property and the [`hyperxmp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp) package with success (I just wasn't getting anything on the PDF properties, except for the same `PTEX.Fullbanner` with value `This is MikTeX 2.9.4535(1.40.13)`

I ran the code presented in question 3 and I still do not get any copyright info in Adobe Reader.

(Question 3 Code):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\makeatletter
  \AtEndDocument{\hyxmp@find@metadata\hyxmp@embed@packet}
\makeatother
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={Brent Longborough},
    pdftitle={O Hai},
    pdfcopyright=Copyright © 2012 by Brent Longborough. All rights reserved.}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I have tried running `pdfLaTeX`, `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX`, but I still have this property empty in the PDF.  I tried removing the `\AtEndDocument{\hyxmp@find@metadata\hyxmp@embed@packet}` and I still got nothing.  Is there something I'm missing?  Is this even possible with Adobe Reader?

**Please note**

I would like not to use any additional file than my .tex one. (That was the idea behind using the `hyperxmp` package

**My specific code**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\title{Titulo}
\author{Autor}
\hypersetup{
    pdfcopyright={\copyright Date by Aauthor.  All rights reserved.}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get it with `pdflatex`. Just see whther this answer: [Add metadata in pdf as type pdf/a](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87913) is useful? Note the ICC profile at the bottom. (just a wild guess).

Comment: @HarishKumar I was trying to avoid using a separate file, hence the use of the `hyperxmp` package.

Comment: I can/must confirm Mario’s observation, Adobe Reader XI (11.0.5) here.

Comment: Adobe Reader does not show the XMP properties - you need Acrobat or, according to the first answer you linked to, PDFXchange, or maybe others, to see the copyright info.

Comment: @Robert Then why on egreg's [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41477/27833) he seems to be using Adobe Reader (although it also seems to be running iOS)?

Comment: @MarioS.E. He's referring to the solution with `\hypersetup{pdfinfo=...}` setting non-standard keys, not XMP. (The "Custom" tab in Document Properties is shown since Adobe Reader X.)

Comment: @Robert but `pdfinfo` does not have any copyright key, check it for yourself: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref

Comment: @Robert Please check my edited question (my own code).  Using Adobe Reader XI (11.0.5, the same as Speravir), I'm not able to see anything under rightclick/Document Properties/Custom Tab except for the PTEX.Fullbanner mentioned in the question

Comment: @MarioS.E. You can put anything you want into `pdfinfo`. Anyway, I concur with @diabonas' answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is working as expected, the problem is that Adobe Reader unfortunately [doesn't support showing these XMP properties](http://www.pdflib.com/knowledge-base/xmp-metadata/xmp-panels/#c3445):

> [N]ote that XMP display is not supported in Adobe Reader[.]

(as already pointed out by [Robert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140892/copyright-metadata-into-adobe-reader-using-pdflatex#comment318240_140892)). In Adobe Acrobat on the other hand, you have a button <kbd>Additional metadata...</kbd> in Document Properties→Description which reveals this dialog:

[image: Additional metadata... dialog with copyright information in Adobe Acrobat]

If you want to also have your copyright information visible in Adobe Reader, you can add a custom metadata field to the document information directory using the `pdfinfo` key (as demonstrated in [How to add copyright information to PDF metadata](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41461/how-to-add-copyright-information-to-pdf-metadata)):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\title{Titulo}
\author{Autor}
\hypersetup{
    pdfcopyright={\copyright Date by Aauthor.  All rights reserved.},
    pdfinfo={
        Copyright={\copyright Date by Aauthor.  All rights reserved.}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Document properties→Custom dialog in Adobe Reader displaying copyright information]

Of course, this is a non-standard approach, but it has the advantage of working with Adobe Reader while still including XMP metadata which e. g. can be extracted automatically.

Comment: Kabooom!!!! the answer I was looking for! :).  Now a few details: Do you think it will work like `pdfinfo={Copyright={\copyright {\@author}.  All rights reserved.}}` ?

Comment: @MarioS.E. This should work, provided that `\hypersetup` is issued after `\author` (and enclosed in `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`, of course).