# Conflict between hyperref and attachfile2 package

Tags: hyperref, incompatibility, attachfile

I have a problem with creating pdf document that contains an attachment. This code works fine:

```
% <xetex — Unicode-based TeX engine>
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, czech, twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{attachfile2}
\begin{document}
   My attached file is \attachfile{my.m}
\end{document}
```

but this code

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, czech, twoside]{book} 
\usepackage[xetex,
            bookmarks={true},    %  A set of Acrobat bookmarks are written
            colorlinks={true},   %  Colors the text of links and anchors. 
            linkcolor={red},     %  Color for normal internal links.
            anchorcolor={black}, %  Color for anchor text.
            filecolor={cyan},    %  Color for URLs which open local files.
            menucolor={red},     %  Color for Acrobat menu items.
            runcolor={blue},     %  Color for run links (launch annotations).
            urlcolor={magenta},  %  Color for linked URLs.          
            unicode={true},  
            pdfauthor={Jaroslav Fait}, 
            pdftitle={Wiking}, 
            pdfsubject={study notes},
            pdfkeywords={linear algebra, math, electronics},
            pdfproducer={XeLateX with hyperref},
            pdfcreator={Xelatex}]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{attachfile2}
\begin{document}
 My attached file is \attachfile{my.m}
\end{document}
```

no!!!. Notes (my.m is Matlab m-file).

The generated pdf document contain an attachment but could not be opened or saved, and the file name of the attachment is corrupted. The result of my investigation is such that the hyperref package shall not have any options. I use Miktex 2.9 (xelatex engine, last update) and Adobe reader X.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried loading the packages in reverse order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works for me by using `\hypersetup` instead of directly supplying the package options:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, czech, twoside]{book} 
\usepackage[xetex,
            bookmarks={true},    %  A set of Acrobat bookmarks are written
            colorlinks={true},   %  Colors the text of links and anchors. 
            linkcolor={red},     %  Color for normal internal links.
            anchorcolor={black}, %  Color for anchor text.
            filecolor={cyan},    %  Color for URLs which open local files.
            menucolor={red},     %  Color for Acrobat menu items.
            runcolor={blue},     %  Color for run links (launch annotations).
            urlcolor={magenta},  %  Color for linked URLs.          
            ]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={Jaroslav Fait}, 
            pdftitle={Wiking}, 
            pdfsubject={study notes},
            pdfkeywords={linear algebra, math, electronics},
            pdfproducer={XeLateX with hyperref},
            pdfcreator={Xelatex}}
\usepackage{attachfile2}
\begin{document}
 My attached file is \attachfile{my.m}
\end{document}
```

(By the way, the `pdfproducer` option won't work as `xdvipdfmx`, the program used by XeTeX to produce the PDF, [always overwrites it with it own entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16438/3323)).

**Edit:** Some more investigation reveals that the problem is induced by using the `hyperref` options `unicode=true`/`pdfencoding=unicode`, which is activated automatically if you use `pdfauthor` and friends as an argument when loading the package. So the solution is to not use one of the options `unicode` or `pdfencoding` and to set `pdfauthor` etc. with `\hypersetup`, which is [recommended practice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12988/3323) anyway.

Comment: `attachfile2` implicitly loads `hyperref` (due to the need for `\pdfstringdef`), so I think you can simply use `hypersetup`.  Also, it is worth mentioning that some options need to be passed to `hyperref` directly at load time.  I always get burned on the `hyperfootnotes` one, e.g.

Comment: @jon Good point! I've had another look into the code, and it seems that the only problematic options are `unicode=true`/`pdfencoding=unicode`, and `pdfauthor` and friends (which set these two automatically if used at load time). So one can use options like `pdfa`, which have to be present when loading the package, without harm, and only supply the document information with `\hypersetup`.

Comment: Thank you very much to all for the help. The solutions works, and in addition, I learned something new. :-)